# System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x800700EA): More data is available

Tags: c#, active-directory

For some reason, on monday, code that was working the previous week suddendly started giving me the following error.

System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException (0x800700EA): More data is available.  Which happens when I try to do a FindAll against an Ad query

I made a small console application and was able to reproduce the error.  What would cause this error to occur?

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var propToLoad = new StringCollection();
        propToLoad.Add(ADProperty.DistinguishedName);

         DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry();
        de.Path = "MySearchROOT";

        DirectorySearcher ser = new DirectorySearcher(de);
        ser.Filter = "(&(&(&(dfaitUserType=PER)(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!dfaitObjectStatus=*)(!msExchHideFromAddressLists=TRUE))(&(sAMAccountName=*)(dfaitOrgCode=*)(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!dfaitObjectStatus=*)(!msExchHideFromAddressLists=TRUE)))(|(employeeType=CBS)(employeeType=LES)(employeeType=CON)(employeeType=OGD)(employeeType=OTH)(employeeType=MIN)))";


// We made constants to represent all the Ad properties
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.Surname);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.GivenName);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.Mail);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.DisplayName);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.DfaitEdsId);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.DistinguishedName);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.MemberOf);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.EmployeeType);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.Department);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.Company);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.MSExchHideFromAddressLists);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.MailNickname);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.Initials);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.TelephoneNumber);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.FacsimileTelephoneNumber);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.Mobile);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.OtherTelephone);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.Name);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.Pager);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.OtherMobile);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.TitleEng);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.TitleFre);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.OtherHomePhone);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.TelephoneAssistant);
            ser.PropertiesToLoad.Add(ADProperty.Mail);
        ser.Sort.PropertyName = ADProperty.DfaitEdsId;
        ser.Sort.Direction = SortDirection.Ascending;
        ser.PageSize = 1000;

        var returnValue = ser.FindAll();

        Console.WriteLine("Total Records found = {0}", returnValue.Count);
        Console.WriteLine();

        foreach (SearchResult res in returnValue)
        {
            var found = GetMultiValue(res, ADProperty.DistinguishedName);
            if (found != null & found.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(found[0]);
            }
        }

    }

            public static string[] GetMultiValue(SearchResult result, string fieldName)
    {
        string[] returnValue = null;

        if (result != null)
        {
            if (result.Properties.Contains(fieldName))
            {
                ResultPropertyValueCollection propertyValue = result.Properties[fieldName];
                if (propertyValue != null)
                {
                    if (propertyValue.Count > 1)
                    {
                        string[] valueArray = new string[propertyValue.Count];
                        for (int i = 0; i < propertyValue.Count; i++)
                        {
                            string valStr = propertyValue[i].ToString();
                            valueArray[i] = valStr;
                        }

                        returnValue = valueArray;
                    }
                    else if (propertyValue.Count == 1)
                    {
                        string[] tempString = new string[] { propertyValue[0].ToString() };
                        returnValue = tempString;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string[] tempString = new string[] { };
                        returnValue = tempString;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the test example above, I commented out the sorting and it worked.

For my main application, I was still getting the error.

Looks like this post still applies with .net 4.0 for this error message.

http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/tomek/archive/2006/11/09/More-data-is-available-exception-when-searching-with-S.DS.aspx

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="system.directoryservices" type="System.DirectoryServices.SearchWaitHandler, System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </configSections>

  <system.directoryservices>
    <DirectorySearcher waitForPagedSearchData="true" />
  </system.directoryservices>
```

Comment: Ran into this issue today, and this solved my problem. Upvoted!

Comment: Hello, what about .core? How we can set wait paged param?

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs once you start to have really too many results for your request.
Whilst this doesn't seem to be well documented, there's apparently a limit on the number of object that *findall* can handle, **even with paging enabled**.

One way out is to switch to a lower level access and use *System.DirectoryServices.Protocols* instead with paging.
 
You can use the code available here for that :
http://dunnry.com/blog/PagingInSystemDirectoryServicesProtocols.aspx

Another option seems to be to use the work around of [KB 833879](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/833789) and activate the waitForPagedSearchData option. However as you describe in your answer, it apparently doesn't solve the problem in all cases. Make sure however that you set the option for the version of DirectoryServices that you are actually using as described here :
https://dirteam.com/tomek/2006/11/09/more-data-is-available-exception-when-searching-with-s-ds/