# Scanning GlobalCatalog via System.DirectoryServices (VB.NET) throws occasional error

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, directoryservices

Objective : Create a simple VB.NET application to scan the GlobalCatalog with a basic filter, limited to predefined properties and write the results to a text file.

Method : Existing code below - this "works" but occasionally throws an exception : *"System.DirectoryServices.SearchResultCollection.ResultsEnumerator.MoveNext() : More data is available"*

Some browsing leads me to think (open to correction) that the issue is caused by attempting to retrieve large volumes of records (in my case roughly 400k) via the DirectorySearcher, despite the results being paginated, and that the solution may be to switch the existing System.DirectoryServices method for something utilising System.DirectoryServices.Protocols. See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268074/system-directoryservices-directoryservicescomexception-0x800700ea-more-data-i) leading to [this article](http://dunnry.com/blog/PagingInSystemDirectoryServicesProtocols.aspx).

However, all the responses I've found, both the links above and others from extensive searching, only provide code snippets in C#, and only seem to query a single record (e.g. retrieve properties based on a specific distinguishedName or login)

I need to retrieve a tonne of records, as quickly and efficiently as possible, using VB.NET. I like the DirectoryServices method because it gives me an easy handle on the GlobalCatalog without having to provide domains or passwords - I can jump straight into the searcher and start specifying filters and properties. And it generally works - but I need it to work every time.

Can anybody advise how I might adapt this code to circumvent the occasional exception and pull back all the data I need in the best possible way?

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices

Public Sub ScanGlobalCatalog()

    Dim searcher As DirectorySearcher = ActiveDirectory.Forest.GetCurrentForest.FindGlobalCatalog.GetDirectorySearcher

    Try
        With searcher
            .Filter = "(&(|(objectClass=user)(objectClass=group))(proxyAddresses=*))"
            .PageSize = 1000
            .SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
            .CacheResults = False
            .PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")
            .PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName")
            .PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName")
            .PropertiesToLoad.Add("proxyAddresses")
        End With

        For Each result As SearchResult In searcher.FindAll()
            Dim properties As ResultPropertyCollection = result.Properties
            Dim sAMAccountName As ResultPropertyValueCollection = properties("sAMAccountName")
            Dim distinguishedName As ResultPropertyValueCollection = properties("distinguishedName")
            Dim displayName As ResultPropertyValueCollection = properties("displayName")
            Dim proxyAddresses As ResultPropertyValueCollection = properties("proxyAddresses")

            ' Check / process / write each property to the output file...
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' Do something...
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: CHeck if `searcher` has a `resultsize` property, and try sending a maxint or whatever actual equivalent of "unlimited" is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Vesper!

Added as shown and it doesn't seem to be happening any more (I believe setting .SizeLimit to 0 equates to 'limitless' but again, open to correction from those with greater knowledge than I...)

```
With searcher
    .Filter = "(&(|(objectClass=user)(objectClass=group))(proxyAddresses=*))"
    .PageSize = 1000
    .SizeLimit = 0
    .SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree
    .CacheResults = False
    .PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName")
    .PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName")
    .PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName")
    .PropertiesToLoad.Add("proxyAddresses")
End With
```

Have been running the script as a service at 15 minute intervals for the last 20 hours or so and I can see 5 or 6 'fails' in the event log - however, previously this would have caused a fatal termination (the service would simply discontinue); now it simply reports the exception and tries again on the next iteration.

The fails are clumped together (consecutive 'runs' within the same hour / hour and a half) and the same service has run uninterrupted and error-free for around 15 hours now, leading me to suspect those fails may have coincided with some kind of maintenance being carried out on the server or some kind of record update mid-read which was throwing the exception. Again, would welcome any insight or opinions on this behaviour.

But I can live with 'occasional' exceptions like this as long as the script generally runs okay and doesn't fall over permanently if/when they arise.

Thanks again for the advice Vesper!